# Discover Bluetooth Devices in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

For working with bluetooth devices I have downloaded one demo from this url https://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor.

I am trying to get the list of nearby bluetooth devices using UUID @"180A" but it is not discovering any devices.

Please help if anyone have implemented this.

**// Changes**

After adding the below request access its show the status is GRANTED. But its not calling their delegates for discover the devices.

```
- (void)requestBluetoothAccess {

if(!self.mgr) {
    self.mgr = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}
/*
 requests to start scanning for bluetooth devices.
 */
CBUUID *heartRate = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"];

// Create a dictionary for passing down to the scan with service method
NSDictionary *scanOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
[self.mgr scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:heartRate] options:scanOptions];
 }
```

Comment: Do you have a peripheral with the heat rate service nearby?  Are you running your app on a real device, not the simulator?

Comment: You need to implement the `centralManagerDidUpdateState` method and only initiate scanning once you are in the powered on state

Comment: I am running on Ipad and don't have heart rate service nearby. I want to detect the bluetooth devices nearby the devices.

Comment: centralManagerDidUpdateState delegate i have implemented and its show the status on / off etc.

Comment: What BLE devices do you have nearby?

Comment: I am checking with Mac and Iphone

Comment: You will need to run an app on those devices to advertise some service before they will be seen

Comment: Without installing the app to other devices we cannot detect them.

Comment: You need some app to advertise a BLE service. You can try the LightBlue app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113915/discussion-between-cj-ios-developer-and-paulw11).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Use `Core Bluetooth Framework`

using `checkBluetoothAccess` and `requestBluetoothAccess` method

```
 - (void)checkBluetoothAccess {

      if(!self.cbManager) {
           self.cbManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
      }

   /*
     Ask to bluetooth manager ahead of time what the authorization status, for our bundle and take the action.
  */

     CBCentralManagerState state = [self.cbManager state];

    if(state == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
          [self alertViewWithDataClass:Bluetooth status:NSLocalizedString(@"UNKNOWN", @"")];
    }
   else if(state == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
          [self alertViewWithDataClass:Bluetooth status:NSLocalizedString(@"DENIED", @"")];
    }
else {
          [self alertViewWithDataClass:Bluetooth status:NSLocalizedString(@"GRANTED", @"")];
  }
}
```

.

```
- (void)requestBluetoothAccess {

  if(!self.cbManager) {
          self.cbManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    }

/*
  requests to start scanning for bluetooth devices.
*/

[self.cbManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];

  }
```

Comment: After implemented its show the GRANTED but not calling the discover devices delegates.

Comment: Once check like this: Go to setting ->bluetooth (you can find the device?)

Comment: then whats the problem now?

Comment: If you care about retrieving BLE devices currently connected from other apps, you can use the retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices: method

Comment: [self.mgr retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:heartRate]]; This function is not calling their delegates. -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals{
    NSLog(@"retrieving!");
}
- (void)scanForPeripheralsWithServices:(NSArray *)serviceUUIDs options:(NSDictionary *)options{
       NSLog(@"scaning!");
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113919/discussion-between-cj-ios-developer-and-suraj-sukale).